# how do I get the field 'aaj' updated with change of date in the following table?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE `aaj` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `aaj` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `mahina` varchar(6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (convert(date_format(`aaj`,'%y/%m') using utf8mb4)) STORED NOT NULL,
  `saptaah` varchar(7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (convert(date_format(`aaj`,'%x/%v') using utf8mb4)) STORED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
CREATE TABLE `aaj` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `aaj` timestamp NOT NULL 
       DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `mahina` varchar(6) GENERATED ALWAYS 
      AS (convert(date_format(`aaj`,'%y/%m') using utf8mb4)) STORED NOT NULL,
  `saptaah` varchar(7) GENERATED ALWAYS 
       AS (convert(date_format(`aaj`,'%x/%v') using utf8mb4)) STORED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Side note: it is usually not a good practice to have a column with the same name as the table (here, `aaj`): from database perspective this is not a problem, but it tends to make things confusing for human beings.

Comment: Thanks for your Response ! I want the to get value of aaj to updated to current date whenever the date in my time zone changes automatically, The front end will not have access this table to update it. This table is to be used for joining with other table where activities with date are available, I want to create view with today's activities only.